# How to add new card using token in Stripe's customer

Tags: javascript, grails, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe token in Java script and I am sending that from ajax call to controller, but It giving an error as **"You cannot use a Stripe token more than once"**, I know that we can't use the same token, but how we can achieve this thing, following is my implementation,

```
// This is Groovy code in controller action
 def CARD_DETAILS_AS_TOKEN = params.token  // getting from Ajax call.
 Customer cu = Customer.retrieve(STRIPE_CUSTOMER_ID)
 Map<String, Object> updateParams = new HashMap<String, Object>()
 updateParams.put("source",CARD_DETAILS_AS_TOKEN)
 cu.update(updateParams)
```

How we can generate new token from Groovy/Java to avoid this issue or Is there any solution to add new card in Stripe's customer? 
Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also add your javascript code?

Comment: You need to create a token, then send that token to the server and add the card to a customer. You can then charge that card from now on through the customer instead of through the token id